# remove array element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am new to javascript & jquery, Need to remove an element from the below array structure

```
[{
    "tag": "tag1",
    "description": "description1"
}, {
    "tag": "tag2",
    "description": "description2"
}, {
    "tag": "tag3",
    "description": "description3"
}]
```

The element to be removed is known `{"tag":"tag2", "description":"description2"}`.

How can i find this element and remove from the array.

Please find the code which i am using to remove an element

```
var actionDic = [];

actionDic.push({
    description: desc,
    tag: tag
});
```

The actionDic array is populated as user enter text in textinput and selects 'add' option.

```
var deleterow = {
    tag: "tag2",
    description: "description2"
};
var index = $.inArray(deleterow, actionDic);
if (index != -1) {
    actionDic.splice(index, 1);
}
```

The correct index is not obtained. Kindly let me know what wrong is in the code.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say _The correct index is not obtained_ then Where is code of `$.actionDic()`?

Comment: I still don't see the code for the function `$.actionDic()`.

Comment: Where is code of __$.actionDic()?__ which you are using to find index. Problem is in that function

Comment: sorry instead of inArray i used actionDic, please find the question updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the comparison between the item to remove and each element in `actionDic` isn't trivial, you could use [`jQuery.grep()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.grep/):

```
actionDic = jQuery.grep(actionDic, function(elem) {
    return elem.tag == deleterow.tag && elem.description == deleterow.description;
}, true);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NgaYM/)

It performs a search using a custom search function and returns the array elements that didn't match. The result replaces the previous value of `actionDic` and effectively removed that one item.

#### Update

Unfortunately, this method could be considered heavy because a new array gets created at each invocation; both in terms of what jQuery can do and standard JavaScript functionality, this particular feature is lacking. ECMAScript 6 will have the [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method that will do the job of finding the index in an array (with which you can perform the splice).

You can of course write one yourself too:

```
(function($) {
  $.find = function(arr, fn) {
    for (var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; ++i) {
      if (fn(arr[i], i, arr)) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
  };
}(jQuery));

var index = $.find(actionDic, function(elem) {
  return elem.tag == deleterow.tag && elem.description == deleterow.description;
});

if (index != -1) {
  actionDic.splice(index, 1);
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/qoqogipu/1/watch?js,console,output)

Comment: I think it should be `!=` instead of `=` in line `elem.tag = deleterow.tag`

Comment: @Satpal Ugh, noob mistake! It should be `==` actually, because of the invert flag that I'm passing as the last argument.

Comment: Yep true, http://jsfiddle.net/su3Gx/ I sometimes gets confused between filter and grep

Comment: @user2071152, here filter example http://jsfiddle.net/NgaYM/ and downvoters comments guys

Answer (score 2):

I've implemented an `indexOfObject` method of `Array prototype` in one of my projects. It searches for an index of `object` by the given `property` name and value. Here it is:

```
Array.prototype.indexOfObject = function(searchTerm, property) {
    for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) {
        if (this[i][property] === searchTerm) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
};
```

You can use this method to find the index of your object using a unique property. In your case you can use it like this:

```
var arr = [{
    "tag": "tag1",
    "description": "description1"
}, {
    "tag": "tag2",
    "description": "description2"
}, {
    "tag": "tag3",
    "description": "description3"
}], deleteObject = {
    tag: "tag2",
    description: "description2"
};

var index = arr.indexOfObject(deleteObject.tag, 'tag');
```

Then you can use that index to remove the object from the array:

```
if (index > -1) {
   arr.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Here is the working example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6h96N/).

Answer (score -1):

```
var actionDic = [{
    "tag": "tag1",
    "description": "description1"
}, {
    "tag": "tag2",
    "description": "description2"
}, {
    "tag": "tag3",
    "description": "description3"
}]

var element = {"tag":"tag2", "description":"description2"}

for(var i=0;i<actionDic.length;i++) {
    var found = false;
    for(each in actionDic[i]) {
        if(actionDic[i][each] == element[each]) {
            found = true
        } else {
            found = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(found) {
        actionDic.splice(i,1);
        found=false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This gets your inner array objects:

```
for (var x = 0; x < actionDic.length; x++){
    var arrayItem = actionDic[x];
    if (arrayItem["tag"] == "tag2"){
        alert(arrayItem["description"]);
    }
}
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4khjp/

Answer (score -1):

You can use [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) which contains many useful helpers for Objects, Arrays etc.

Removing array element:

```
array = _.reject(array, function(item) {
 return item.tag == 'tag2'; // <- if tag is unique to whole array
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, OP isn't using Underscore.